# excel calculate number of days per month in certain period

Tags: excel

I know this has been asked many times.. but I cannot make it work for my scenario. I need to calculate number of days occupancy between 2 dates, but I need to consider year as well... (IE. jan-2020 till dec 2021.

My formula for calculations is: `=MAX(0; MIN(EOMONTH(C$1; 0); $B2)-MAX(C$1; $A2) +1)` where C1 is month that I am looking for, B2 is end date, A2 is start date...

here is my screenshot:

[image: sheet]

This is results that I am expecting:

[image: expected results]

I think I am having issue with formatting that I don't know how to overcome... with more testing it looks like my formula was fine in the first place:

1. I create blank sheet and I manually add start dates - end dates and header column months to try formula, format it like date (with * as date - *14.3.20) and it worked fine... this is my screenshot:

[image: manual entry]

2. When I copy paste start dates and end dates from different sheet (I already have thousands of start-end dates... it would be impossible to manually enter all of them). Than I paste special - just values, then in format I choose date, same format as my testing excel sheet... nothing it simply won't work... how I can format dates on pasted values? Here is screenshot that it is wrong...

[image: wrong manaul entry]

I selected start date column and end date column than:

Data > Text to Columns Next, Next, then select Date 'DMY'.... did the trick.

Start and end dates are converted back to dates and everything started working for me....

Dates where imported from database and they had leading space in front of it... that is why calculations failed. Once they are back to real dates everything started working...

Thanks for help guys!

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: sorry I didn't put that.. most important thing. It should be jan2020 til oct2020 0 as result, than Nov2020 - 20, Dec2020 - 31, Jan2021 - 31... and so till Nov2021

Comment: Update your question with all the relevant information (and preferably a markdown sample data example table instead of a screenshot).

Comment: apologies, my bad, I just did.

Comment: are column headers formatted as date?

Comment: All dates (including column headers) are formatted as "Custom: dd.mm.yyyy".

Comment: I got confused? Earlier you told all are formatted as dates. Now I am unable to get which values aren't dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just posting another IF based variation which I had worked out.

`=IF(OR(AND(C$1>$A2,$B2>C$1),AND(EOMONTH(C$1,0)>$A2,$B2>EOMONTH(C$1,0))),MIN($B2,EOMONTH(C$1,0))-MAX($A2,C$1)+1,0)`

Primary condition is to check whether any date mentioned on row 1 (within the month) is intersecting the either start or end date specified in cell `A2` and `B2`. Once this is cleared then the primary logic which you had posted works just fine.

You will have to change the argument separators as per your locale!

**Edit**-

@AnilGoyal spotted the formula error and I am posting the revised formula. I have put those missing `AND` conditions in `OR`. In addition to that the formula would have missed a boundary condition where date was first or last day of the month.

`=IF(OR(AND(C$1>=$A2,C$1<=$B2),AND(EOMONTH(C$1,0)>=$A2,EOMONTH(C$1,0)<=$B2),AND($A2<=EOMONTH(C$1,0),$A2>=C$1),AND($B2<=EOMONTH(C$1,0),$B2>=C$1)),MIN($B2,EOMONTH(C$1,0))-MAX($A2,C$1)+1,0)`

Overall, OP's original formula shall work well. As it turns out below formula seems to work just fine as well.
`=MAX(0,MIN($B2,EOMONTH(E$1,0))-MAX($A2,E$1)+1)`

Comment: it looks like my formula is OK, I just don't know how to format pasted dates as dates...

Comment: But I just noticed an issue, which isn't there in my formula!  If start date and end dates are in same month, it returns 0 instead of calculating the diff!! [image](https://imgur.com/a/jg5ndDE)

Comment: @AnilGoyal Thank you for testing and informing. I have posted a revised approach.

Answer (score 2):

ENTER THIS FORMULA IN C2

```
=IF(AND(C$1<MIN($A2,$B2),MONTH($A2)>MONTH(C$1)),0,IF(C$1>MAX($A2,$B2), 0,IF(C$1>=MIN(C$1,$A2),MIN(EOMONTH(C$1,0),$B2)-MAX($A2,C$1)+1,-MIN($B2,C$1)+$A2+1)))
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like my formula is OK, I just don't know how to format pasted dates as dates...

Comment: Sorry, I was working all the time on pasted data, and it didn't work for me at all. Only when I found out that when I manually enter dates it started working.. I immediately edited my question. So simply I didn't know, sorry...